# OAuth 2.0 Example Auth Server

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, slim

I want to try with this OAuth2-Server Example ( `https://github.com/alexbilbie/oauth2-example-auth-server` ) but when I want to run it gives me error `" Fatal error: Interface 'OAuth2\Storage\ClientInterface' not found in /var/www/oauth2-auth-server/model_client.php on line 2 "`

I think I need to add autoloader to composer.json I did it but forever it gives me this error. But I also think in oauth.php I found this line:

```
// Initiate the auth server with the models
$server = new \OAuth2\AuthServer(new ClientModel, new SessionModel, new ScopeModel);
```

But there is no any `AuthServer` in the OAuth folder? Is there anybody used this example. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a `composer.json` file along with Composer to install and manage dependencies?

Comment: Yes Brodie, I am using composer.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autoloading is done automatically using Composer assuming you've downloaded the dependencies from modules stated in the `require` key of your `composer.json` file. Just include this at the top of your PHP script to access the Classes:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/to/vendor/autoload.php';
```

If these are manually downloaded packages you'll need to point the autoloader to them and run `composer update`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "Util\\": "assets/"
  },
  "files": ["assets/Util/init.php"]
}
```

The above automatically:

- appends the script at `assets/Util/init.php` to every file where the autoloader is run;
- and autoloads classes from, in this example, the Util namespace (has to be in a folder called Util to meet psr-0 convention so is actually at `assets/Util/`) into any file that runs the autoloader

You may also need to manage namespace issues using the `use Namespace\Class as Class;` syntax.

Comment: The problem was in namespaces, I added in autloader in composer file and change correct namespace to folder it worked thanks!