# OAuth 2.0 Server PHP, interfaces not found

Tags: php, interface, namespaces, oauth-2.0

I got a small problem with [OAuth 2.0 Server PHP](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/), i want use it in my project. Here is the tree view of my project:

> /Model/ Contains all the classes for managing API
>
> /Lib/ Contains all third-party libraries

The root namespace is "IO" for models that is "IO\Model" and libraries is "IO\Lib". The problem I have comes from the namespace, currently the class "IO\Lib\OAuth2\Storage\Pdo" is well known but the interfaces are not found. I've never had this problem before on other projects.

The OAuth 2.0 Server PHP library to its own namespace "OAuth2". Here is my script Auth.php:

```
namespace IO\Model;

use IO\Lib\OAuth2 as OAuth2;

class Auth {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->config = Config::getInstance();
    
    $storage = new OAuth2\Storage\Pdo(
      array(
        'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname='.$this->config->sql_database.';host='.$this->config->sql_host,
        'username' => $this->config->sql_user,
        'password' => $this->config->sql_password
      )
    );
    $server = new OAuth2\Server($storage);
  }
}
```

I got this error :

> Fatal error: Interface 'OAuth2\Storage\AuthorizationCodeInterface' not found in /Lib/OAuth2/Storage/Pdo.php on line 19

Comment: Are you not using Composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per previous answer if autoloader fails then solution for running loader manually
is given below

#### [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092104/oauth-2-0-example-auth-server)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of you OAuth2 library files is referencing `Oauth2\Storage\AuthorizationCodeInterface` in one or more of its files. The problem is that the library is self-contained and expects to reside in the namespace `OAuth2`. You put it into the namespace `IO\Lib\OAuth2`.

I don't know which method you are using for loading your files (autoloader?), but you should include third-party libraries in a way which preserves their namespace.

Answer (score 1):

From this reference : http://alexbilbie.com/2013/02/securing-your-api-with-oauth-2/

Did you installed oauth with composer ?
That's a possibility for not autoloading your interface ( no autoloader )